# Disable smart lock Google OAuth with firebase web

Tags: javascript, firebase, cordova, oauth

I have implemented the Google OAuth in my app. Everything works but now, I can't change the login account. When I click on "login", he takes my account and I cannot change it. I use signinwithredirect.

```
     var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
        firebase
          .auth()
          .signInWithRedirect(provider)
          .then(() => {
            return firebase.auth().getRedirectResult();
          })
```

Even after I signed out the user I cannot change the user.

```
 firebase
.auth()
.signOut()
.then(() => {
  // Sign-out successful.
})
.catch((error) => {
  // An error happened.
});
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/wpntS7RLha8

Comment: Thanks! Now it works